# Messed up /etc permissions

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, opensuse

I was going to modify my.conf file so I wanted to change its permissions, but I ran the code in the current dir instead of only the file

Now all files in the /etc (and the folders) have 777 permissions. Now when I run a terminal, it shows "/etc/bash.bashrc: Permission denied" error.

Also I was using proxy and now proxy is also does not work and I cannot reach to the internet from that machine.

I am using OpenSuse...

How can I fix all permissions?

Comment: Sorry pal, but setting up permissions in /etc is kinda messy. If you have a spare machine I would suggest to try to change de permissions, but maybe a reinstall would be easier...

Comment: @Ivan: A reinstall is overkill, most files are 644, most directories 755. Only some files must be 600 (like `/etc/shadow` and `/etc/ssh/ssh_host*`) or 755 (like scripts in `/etc/init.d` and `/etc/sysconfig/network/scripts/`).

Comment: @jaume: thanks. I will try the answer first then yours

Comment: Thanks, but my comment only says "don't panic!" and explains a quick repair, don't promote it to an answer :-) I'd recommend that you thoroughly repair permissions, either using Zhen's script below or by other means.

Answer (score 4):

You need another similar machine with also OpenSuse (or install a Virtual Machine image). You should be able to do ssh against this image:

Put a simple script in this server, like (e.g: call it show_permission and put on the $HOME):

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -e $1 ]
then
   find $1 -printf "%m %p\n" 
else
   echo ERROR $1
fi
```

Then, in your ill-server, you can execute this:

```
find /etc/ -exec ssh <IMAGE_SERVER> ./show_permission {} ";"
```

to get the permissions to restore. The lines that start with ERROR, will need manual fix.

With this command you will get a permission list of /etc files. Append chmod to all lines and execute. Double check it first, this time :D

Comment: This would work if he can access the machine.

Comment: @Ivan, well. I didn't test it with a VM image, but its a good option to get a similar machine.

Comment: Agreed, @Zhen, just not sure what is his condition: if he can ssh into the machine, if he has physical access, and if he has a spare machine. It seems to me that your script would work - and I gave it an upvote.